# POSTGRESQL - Traer informacion de 2 tablas con 1 campo en comun

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente escenario:

2 Tablas
Paciente y Actividad

La tabla Paciente contiene: DNI, Nombre y Apellido.
La tabla Actividad contiene: DNI del paciente, Actividad.

Dentro de la tabla de actividades tengo repetidas las DNI de los pacientes varias veces (Ya que realizan varias actividades).

**Necesito** una consulta donde me pueda traer los DNI sin ser repetidos de la tabla Actividad y los nombres y apellidos de la tabla Paciente.

He intentado con count pero me da errores usandolo junto con group by

Comment: @Shaz No veo por qué tener `DNI` repetidos en la tabla `Actividad` podría ser un problema de diseño

Comment: @Shaz No veo en ninguna parte de la pregunta algo que haga mención a que no están referenciados como FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que necesitas un simple `JOIN`. Hay varias formas de lograr que el `DNI` sea único, pero una alternativa es:

```
SELECT  A.DNI,
        P.Nombre,
        P.Apellido
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT DNI
        FROM Actividad) AS A
INNER JOIN Paciente AS P
    ON A.DNI = P.DNI;
```

Otra alternativa que imagino será más rápida es usar `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Paciente AS P
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Actividad
             WHERE DNI = P.DNI);
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar un **inner join**:

```
select pa.dni, pa.nombre, pa.apellido, ac.actividad from Paciente pa
inner join Actividad ac on pa.dni = ac.dni
```

pa es un alias de la tabla Paciente, lo mismo que ac de Actividad.

Comment: El problema con esta consulta es que me repite los DNI de las personas, necesitaba agruparlos.. Ya utilice un EXISTS, muchas gracias igualmente!